# error while loading osm2po routing sql-script into PostgreSQL

Tags: postgis, openstreetmap, osm2po

please advice what could be wrong in my situation:

- I succesfully generated sql-file using osm2po
- I tried to run it within PostgreSQL and got the following error:

  ```
  ********** Error **********

  ERROR: Table 'BY2_2po_4pgr' does not occur in the search_path
  SQL state: P0001
  Context: SQL statement "SELECT AddGeometryColumn('','',$1,$2,$3,$4,$5, $6)"
  PL/pgSQL function "addgeometrycolumn" line 5 at SQL statement
  ```

Working on Win7(x64) with PostgreSQL 9.1 and PostGIS 2.0.1
osm2po ver 4.5.25

Any ideas appreciated!

Comment: it looks like addgeometrycolumn fails but why? (db looks like postGIS enabled - I see spatial_ref_sys table)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just an assumption: Maybe this is a lower/upper case problem.
Try it with "by2" instead of "BY2"

Comment: yes, this is correct assumption - see my answer below

Answer (score 0):

The problem solved. Actual issue was in upper case characters in the table name, i.e. call

```
SELECT AddGeometryColumn('BY2_2po_4pgr', 'geom_way', 4326, 'LINESTRING', 2);
```

returns mentioned above error, while call

```
SELECT AddGeometryColumn('by2_2po_4pgr', 'geom_way', 4326, 'LINESTRING', 2);
```

executes without any problems.
Thus **it is not recommended to use upper case letters for prefix name in osm2po**!!

Comment: This is half true because it only relates to the generation of sql files for PostGIS. The intrinsic reason for this bad behavior is that a CREATE TABLE in PostgreSQL allows upper case letters, but auto converts them into lower case and PostGIS then fails with its AddGeometryColumn. Nevertheless, this is sth. I should make safe in the next version.

Comment: agree. in ideal case PostGIS should have consistent with Postgres behavior in working with table names